# How to get the value of the text box using jQuery on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want  a functionality that i will type some text on the textbox and the value will be picked up by the jquery and will be stored in some variable ,how to achieve that? i am using jquery bind function but it is not suiting my purpose .
This is my textbox

```
<aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="interviewCC" id="interviewCC" size="45" value=""></aui:input>
```

and i am using this jQuery function

```
$("#interviewCC").bind("click", function () {
     value = $("#interviewCC").val();
     alert(value)
 });
```

but it is not picking the value i want that when i will type something on the textbox that value will be picked up.Please somebody help.

Comment: Why are you using bind and not on? Your question talks about keypress but you are binding to the click event? click != keypress

Comment: Well.... basically it works like you did it: http://jsfiddle.net/m1eejz7w/ I just changed the `<aui:input>` to a normal `<input>` because I dont knwo what that should be and jsfiddle neither

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you listen to the 'click' event and not the 'keypress' event.

Try this:

```
$('#interviewCC').keypress( function(e) {

    var value = $("#interviewCC").val();
    alert(value)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#interviewCC").keypress(function () {
   value = $("#interviewCC").val();
   alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery function `.keyup()` which will figure out when a key has been pressed and then the press has finished.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#text').keyup(function() {
    $('.output').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" />
<div class="output"></div>
```

- [`.keyup()` Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)